# Can't create a border outside of my width-specified element

Tags: css, border

My page content is `960px` wide. One container (`#element`, see below) in it must have a semi-transparent border, leaving the background of the page slightly visible.

```
#element {
    width: 950px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

`#element` along with its border should be `960px` wide, its border being semi-transparent leaving page background visible. Instead, it's 950px with its border "inside", leaving not the page background visible underneath but `#element` itself.

Why is that?

Comment: Looks like you have `box-sizing` set to `border-box` by default. Try adding the rule `box-sizing: content-box` to your class, or just set the width as 960px

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `box-sizing` CSS property:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Try to specify that you want to include content, padding and border (by default `box-sizing` includes only the content), like that:

```
#element {
    box-sizing: content-box
    width: 950px;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Danield is right, check out this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5cetxj6t/3/

Some CSS reset may set

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

by default

Comment: There's no need to target every single element on the page. It can produce unexpected results depending on the structure.

Comment: Just sayin that this comportment is probably set by a framework or css reset, of course that he should not target every element, sorry if misunderstanding